# ¿Se puede definir el nombre de una estructura con una variable?

Tags: c, estructuras-de-datos, estructuras, struct

la cuestion es la siguiente ( tengan en cuenta que recien estoy aprendiendo C):
Supongamos que defino una estructura similar a esta

```
 struct Alumnos{  
 char asignatura[25];  
 int nota;  
  };
```

y quiero que el usuario ingrese un apellido,guardarlo en una variable de tipo `char` y enviarselo a una funcion que lo unico que hace es crear una.. (no se como se llamaria una estructura de Alumnos?) me refierio a :

```
struct Alumnos -Aca la variable char con el apellido-;
```

supongamos .. el apellido "ramirez",guardado en la variable `char`:

```
char apellido[]="ramirez";  
struct Alumnos apellido;
```

y despues ingresar los datos asignatura y nota asi:

```
apellido.nota=4;
```

¿Esto es posible?,y de ser asi ¿Como se hace?(solo les muestro mi idea pero obviamente no funciona), estuve revolviendo un poco por otros foros y encontre algo como esto:

```
int cont=0;
struct agenda {

    char nom[15];

    int t_f;

    int t_m;

    char dir[30], email[40], grupos[12];

} control[100];
```

y luego dentro de la funcion "agregar contacto " lo que se hacia era

```
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("\n%d.Nombre de contacto:", (cont+1));

    gets(control[cont].nom);
```

pero no me convence y no lo entiendo del todo,ademas quiero que se acceda a los datos de esa estructura con el apellido,asi si alguien quiere consultarlo puede hacerlo ingresando el apellido..en fin,esa es mi duda,agradezco que me ayuden.Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

> Supongamos que defino una estructura similar a esta ...

El nombre de la estructura no es el más adecuado... esa estructura solo guarda información de un alumno... al llamarla `Alumnos` se entiende que almacena información de varios alumnos lo cual es una asunción falsa. Para este caso sería más apropiado usar el singular

```
struct Alumno {  // ...
```

E incluso yo iría un poco más allá... realmente no se está almacenando información de un alumno sino que realmente almacena las notas de un alumno. El nombre más apropiado sería entonces:

```
struct Asignatura{ // ...
```

> y quiero que el usuario ingrese un apellido,guardarlo en una variable de tipo char y enviarselo a una funcion que lo unico que hace es crear una...

Aquí yo entiendo que la estructura `Alumno` debe almacenar también, al menos, el apellido de un alumno... entonces lo que pretendes es que la función inicialice una estructura de tipo `Alumno` con el apellido que se le pasa como argumento. Peeero claro,

```
struct Asignatura{  
 char asignatura[25];  
 int nota;  
};

struct Alumno
{
  char apellido[50];
  struct Asignatura asignaturas[4]; // <<---
};
```

Eso sí, llegados a este punto habría que saber si el número de asignaturas es fijo (yo he asumido 5) o es variable, en cuyo caso quizás sería mejor esto:

```
struct Alumno
{
  char apellido[50];
  int numAsignaturas;
  struct Asignatura *asignaturas;
};
```

Pero no es algo que detalles en la pregunta... esta parte queda en tus manos. Para el resto de la respuesta asumiré que la opción elegida es la primera.

El caso... ya tenemos las estructuras definidas... falta la función:

```
struct Alumno NuevoAlumno(char const* apellido)
{
  struct Alumno alumno;

  // Inicializamos todos los bytes a 0
  // Con esto conseguimos que todos los campos de la estructura estén inicializados.
  // No es imprescindible, pero lo prefiero a inicializar las notas con un for
  memset(&alumno,0,sizeof(alumno)); 

  strcpy(alumno.apellido,apellido); // Copiamos el apellido en la estructura

  return alumno;  
}
```

Con esto ya podrías hacer algo tal que:

```
struct Alumno alumno = NuevoAlumno("ramirez");
alumno.asignaturas[0].nota = 4;

printf("%s %d\n",alumno.apellido, alumno.asignaturas[0].nota);
```

Comment: Hola, una consulta: en la parte donde usas la función `memset`, no debería ser `memset(&alumno, 0, sizeof(alumno))`?

Comment: @Xam si, cierto. Ahora lo cambio.  Gracias